# popup alert after pressing copy in UIWebVIew

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have app with UIWebView, by default when someone taps and hold on link in web view action sheet pops up with copy, add to reading list and cancel option, I'm trying to popup alert showing link that is copied in pasteboard when user selects copy option.

i have tried

```
override func copy() 
{
 // println("copied")
}
```

but nothing shows in log saying copied. i found another way it can be done with uipasteboardnotification changed, but I'm not sure how to use this.
can someone point me in right direction?

I'm using swift language, Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of type `UIPasteBoard`. Pasteboard objects can contain shared data between applications. When you use `cut`, `copy` and `paste` functions, values are stored in the pasteboard object, accessible across applications.

For your example, you can use the `generalPasteboard` method to access the standard shared Pasteboard. When you are done copying from the `UIWebView`, you can access the copied text with code like this:

```
var pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
println(pasteBoard.string)
```

For more information - [UIPasteBoard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uipasteboard_class/index.html)

Comment: thanks but thats not the problem, i want to have my custom method of alert popup automatically right after copy button has been clicked.